# jQuery UI Effects Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have jQuery, jQuery UI, and jQuery UI Effects enqueued properly, and in the correct order; however I keep getting an error when trying to apply an effect to a show/hide in jQuery. I'm passing a variable through `wp_localize_script()` from a shortcode for use in jQuery, this is also working correctly. If I test the object with an alert it shows the correct value.

This is the error I am receiving: 
[image]

This is the jQuery snippet I'm using:

```
jQuery('.aw_ss_post_wrapper').each(function() {
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass(aw_ss_button_ID)) {

                var myUIeffect = aw_ss_script_vars.jQueryUIeffect;
                var options = {};

                if ( myUIeffect === "scale" ) {
                    options = { percent: 0 };
                } else if ( myUIeffect === "size" ) {
                    options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
                }

                jQuery(this).hide(myUIeffect, options, 800);        

            } else {
                jQuery(this).show(myUIeffect, options, 800);
            }
        });
```

Am I missing something here? If I remove the jQuery UI affect from the show/hide snippet, everything works as intended. I only get this error when I try to use the effect. On a side not, the variable `aw_ss_button_ID` is being set correctly as well, its just in a snippet of code further up in the main function. The above jQuery snippet is also wrapped in a `.ready()`.

Comment: Is jQueryUI being included *before* jQuery by accident?

Comment: No, the order is correct. jQuery, jQuery UI, jQuery Effcts, then my document ready script.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when jQueryUI doesn't recognize the effect. Here's a fiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpx8rnaL/

One could argue that the error is neither specific nor indeed helpful...

You can get around this by wrapping your variable in something that checks if such an effect is valid, and defaulting to some other desired value (or `undefined`, for no effect):

```
 if(jQuery.effects.effect[myUIeffect]) {
     jQuery(this).hide(myUIeffect, options, 800);
 }
 else {
     jQuery(this).hide("scale", options, 800);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately implementing this throws the same error.

Comment: It doesn't here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpx8rnaL/1/ Perhaps it comes out of `.show`? I don't know where you've set your outer `myUIEffect`, but it's not the same as the one in your `.hide`. Otherwise, could you make a MCVE?

Comment: I'm lost with this one. I changed the `.show` to not consider the effect at all, and just use a plain old `.show` and the error still persists. Mind taking a look and see if something jumps out to you? http://build.andywarren1.com/simple-sorter/

Comment: Well the linked page doesn't have the guard `if` described above. You're getting an error because you're trying to call `.hide()` with an empty string (`....hide("", {}, 800)`). The `.show` OTOH is working fine

Comment: Sorry, it did had the if described above, pulled it out to test other things. The string is populated now, that was from me working with the shortcode attribute. Still the error. I'll leave it alone if you don't mind taking another look.

Comment: Hm, that *is* weird, error coming from somewhere else (queues, perhaps? can't really tell) I'd recommend you try to debug it with the non-minified versions of $ and $.ui

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69471/discussion-between-andywarren-and-blgt).

Comment: Just thought I'd throw this out there, if I use my own enqueued copy of the full jQuery UI my code works, but if I try to enqueue the copy of jQuery UI and jQuery Effects bundled with WordPress I get the error above.

Comment: That's strange but good to know; you could add it to the question or as a separate answer if it worked out for you

Comment: Submitted it to WordPress Trac as a possible bug with the bundled jQuery UI and jQuery Effects. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31111 We'll see.